# Python Dict prints last place on first place

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I made the following dict:

```
    logs = {
    '3h forecast': {
        'Ort': '',
        'Datum und Uhrzeit': '',
        'Temperatur': '',
        'Temperatur_Min': '',
        'Temperatur_Max': ''},

    '6h forecast': {
        'Ort': '',
        'Datum und Uhrzeit': '',
        'Temperatur': '',
        'Temperatur_Min': '',
        'Temperatur_Max': ''},

    '9h forecast': {
        'Ort': '',
        'Datum und Uhrzeit': '',
        'Temperatur': '',
        'Temperatur_Min': '',
        'Temperatur_Max': ''},

    '12h forecast': {
        'Ort': '',
        'Datum und Uhrzeit': '',
        'Temperatur': '',
        'Temperatur_Min': '',
        'Temperatur_Max': ''}
}
```

and print it with following line:

```
print(json.dumps(logs, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

and the result in the console is this:

> {
> "12h forecast": {
> "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
> "Ort": "",
> "Temperatur": "",
> "Temperatur_Max": "",
> "Temperatur_Min": ""
> },
> "3h forecast": {
> "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
> "Ort": "",
> "Temperatur": "",
> "Temperatur_Max": "",
> "Temperatur_Min": ""
> },
> "6h forecast": {
> "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
> "Ort": "",
> "Temperatur": "",
> "Temperatur_Max": "",
> "Temperatur_Min": ""
> },
> "9h forecast": {
> "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
> "Ort": "",
> "Temperatur": "",
> "Temperatur_Max": "",
> "Temperatur_Min": ""
> }
> }

So... Why is the 12h forecast now on the first place and not like the logs `dict` on the last place?

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: I think you want to use `sort_keys=False` or just remove the `sort_keys` parameter

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `print(json.dumps(logs, sort_keys=True, indent=4))`, specifically what do you expect the `sort_keys=True` part to mean?

Comment: Hint: `'12' < '3' == True`

Comment: @0x5453 That's false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `sort_keys=True`

```
print(json.dumps(logs, indent=4))
```

#output

```
{
    "3h forecast": {
        "Ort": "",
        "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
        "Temperatur": "",
        "Temperatur_Min": "",
        "Temperatur_Max": ""
    },
    "6h forecast": {
        "Ort": "",
        "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
        "Temperatur": "",
        "Temperatur_Min": "",
        "Temperatur_Max": ""
    },
    "9h forecast": {
        "Ort": "",
        "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
        "Temperatur": "",
        "Temperatur_Min": "",
        "Temperatur_Max": ""
    },
    "12h forecast": {
        "Ort": "",
        "Datum und Uhrzeit": "",
        "Temperatur": "",
        "Temperatur_Min": "",
        "Temperatur_Max": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, its that simple - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What happened here is that you were sorting the keys based on strings.
So the `'1'` from `'12'` got compared with the `'3'` from the other forecast.
And because `'1'` is lower than `'3'` in the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) it is placed earlier in the list.

You can check this behavior yourself by comparing

```py
'9' < '10'
```

to

```py
9 < 10
```

To prevent this is in this specific case you can remove the `sort_keys` attribute.